# Issues with creating an Array with multiple spaces in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to parse information from an xml using powershell, the problem is that the line I need to build the array with has multiple spaces but needs to be broken up into groups. Any help is appreciated. 
EX:
[X] Peer Name Resolution Protocol PNRP Installed

Needs to be broken up into the following groups:
[X]
Peer Name Resolution Protocol
PNRP
Installed

I can't seem to figure out how to use the split to separate them.

Comment: Can you show us sample xml input and the current code your working with?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't give as an example of data you have in the XML-File. I just did a small script with the one you gave us.
You can use the `-split` operator:

```
$oldline = "[X] Peer Name Resolution Protocol PNRP Installed"
$tmp = ($oldline -split " ")   
$line1 = $tmp[0]
$line2 = "$($tmp[1]) $($tmp[2]) $($tmp[3]) $($tmp[4])"
$line3 = $tmp[5]
$line4 = $tmp[6]
```

Comment: I used some of this in combination with what I was doing and now it pulls it exactly as we need it, thank you so much!